# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated using Selenium and HtmlUnit

Tags: ssl, selenium, htmlunit

I am attempting to load a page with Selenium for testing, but I keep getting this javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated error. Now I have tried MANY different ways of allowing it, but it simply will not work!

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(){
            protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client){
                try {                   
                    client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
                    client.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
                    client.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
                    client.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError( false );
                    client.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode( true );
                    client.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode( true );
                    client.setCssEnabled( true );
                    client.setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
                    XTrustProvider.install(); // Allow all certs
                    SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();// to turn off the default hostname verification on HTTPS connection;
                    SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();// to turn off the default certificate validation on HTTPS 
                } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 return client;
               }
            } ;
```

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. It seems to be a bug in HtmlUnit with the currently available 2.9 version released in 2011. I built it from source and now it works!